# How to get row height in tabular?

Tags: tables, rules, superscripts

I want to calculate row height that I could change tabular vertical rule.
Everything is fine if I don't use superscript. But with superscript I don't get correct 
height of vertical line (`\vline`).

Original `\vline` doesn't sets height so it draws across the whole row.
Original `\vline` form latex.ltx:

```
\def\vline{\vrule \@width \arrayrulewidth}
```

MVE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter

\def\hline@skip{2\p@}
% adding 2pt vertical skip to hline (above/below) 
\def\hline{%
  \noalign{\vskip\hline@skip}%
  \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
  \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth 
  \futurelet\reserved@a\@xhline}

\def\@xhline{\ifx\reserved@a\hline
  \vskip\doublerulesep\vskip-\arrayrulewidth\fi
  \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
  \noalign{\vskip\hline@skip}}%

\def\vline{%  
  \vbox to\z@{\hsize=\arrayrulewidth
    \noindent
    \hbox to \arrayrulewidth{%
      \vbox to \z@{%
        \kern -\dimexpr\arraystretch \ht\@arstrutbox + \hline@skip\relax
        \noindent
        \vrule
        \@height \dimexpr\arraystretch \ht\@arstrutbox + \hline@skip + \hline@skip\relax 
        \@depth \arraystretch \dp \@arstrutbox 
        \@width \arrayrulewidth
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l|c|c}
 \hline
   A & X & B \\
 \hline
   $2^{O^{A}}$ & & 10 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Output with original `\hline`:
[image]

Output with edited `\hline` (2pt space above/below):
[image]

**red line shows the problematic gap which I don't now how to calculate.**
Any suggestions???

Comment: what do you want it to do (that the original does not)?

Comment: For example I want to make higher rules to reach the \hline if they don't. This happens if I add a vertical space above/belove \hline (hooking the \hline macro with \vskip)

Comment: But a standard vline fills the space if the extra space is added as intended by placing a strut into the row below, and that is why I asked what you want to do, if your original question had been answered it would (if I'd have had time to do it) show the height of the box constructed by tex for that row which would _not_ include anything added by \noalign _above_ that row.

Comment: David, \strut in \noalign adds vertical space, but then \vline do not expands till \hline too.

Comment: No, you should put a big strut _in the row_ not in \noalign that increases the row height so vline naturally fills it.